# why use ftp when scp is available?

Tags: ssh, ftp, webserver, scp

Many webhosts etc want you to upload files using `ftp` or `sftp`. Yet I always found that `scp` is faster and simple works better (more like the local `cp` command).

What are the advantages `ftp` has to offer over `scp`? Or what other reason is there to choose `ftp` over `scp`, at least from a webhosts perspective?

I ask this because I recently set up my own webserver and have now got acces to all configuration options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's your own server, stay with `scp`.

Hosting companies just offer FTP because it's more widely adopted and more people know how to use it (compared to SSH).

Comment: Yes, but most servers even block out `scp` and `ssh`. Why is that?

Comment: Maybe the host provider doesn't want to support it. I'd say SSH/SCP is a more complex topic than just FTP. If you want to provide SCP without a shell, you need to set up `rssh` or `scponly` or something. It can get complicated fast enough.

Comment: @romeovs: They don't want to provide a shell. As long as they provide SFTP that's ok, if they don't then ditch them.

Answer (score 0):

Most of web related people know about the FTP but it not same in case of SCP. If its your own server then using SCP is fine, but if you need to give anyone else some access to upload files in portion of server, FTP is best option then, as you can't handle full control via SSH.

Also for shared hosting accounts they only give ftp access, so that end user have limited access, not the control of full server.

With FTP some third party will just add/remove files at most but SCP access in wrong hands will do no good at all.